# update_alert_policy() unexpected argument

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm building a cloud functions to update alert policies based on an external table I use as a reference.

I already have a cloud functions to create alert policies:

```
name = 'projects/my_project'
filter = "some_filters"
alert_policy = {"conditions":[{"conditionAbsent":{"duration": "1800s","filter": '{}'.format(filter)}, "displayName":"test_name"}], "displayName":"test_name", "combiner":"OR"}
policy = monitoring_v3.AlertPolicy.from_json(json.dumps(alert_policy))
client_alert.create_alert_policy(name=name, alert_policy=policy)
```

My initial plan was to reuse this code and replacing the `create_alert_policy` method by the `update_alert_policy` method. I have something like this:

```
name = 'projects/my_project/alertPolicies/1234555665'
filter = "some_filters"
alert_policy = {"conditions":[{"conditionAbsent":{"duration": "1800s","filter": '{}'.format(filter)}, "displayName":"test_name"}], "displayName":"test_name", "combiner":"OR"}
policy = monitoring_v3.AlertPolicy.from_json(json.dumps(alert_policy))
client_alert.update_alert_policy(name=name, alert_policy=policy)
```

I have the following error: `update_alert_policy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`; what do I'm missing here?

Comment: Try removing name argument in second block of the code, I think it should be like " alert_client.update_alert_policy(alert_policy=policy) ". For more information refer this [document](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-api#api-replace-channels).

Comment: @Sri I tried and I have the following error `details = "Request was missing field name.""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update_alert_policy` should be passed like this:

`client_alert.update_alert_policy(alert_policy=policy)` and the name should be passed directly in the json object.